# Power steering squeak

Tags: chevrolet, power-steering, blazer

So I was wondering if someone could help me with this issue . My truck is a 1989 s10 blazer with a 4.3l V6 tbi engine. Yesterday I noticed a constant squeak and whine when I turn the steering . So I checked the power steering fluid and noticed it was almost empty. Topped it up and the sound still persists. It's not as loud as before but its still there.. I was wondering what could be causing the noise.

I was wondering if someone can help me debug this issue ?.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

the whine would be the pump.  It could have air in it still or you could have damaged it running it low.  A squeak would be the belt slipping.